# jQuery validation engine using the “ajax[selector]”

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

**I have the following (multistep form) HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">
  <fieldset id="first_step">        
      <input type="text" name="register" placeholder="Αρ. Μητρώου" id="register" class="validate[required,custom[integer]]" />
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Πόλη" id="city" class="validate[required,ajax[email]]" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Επόμενο" id="next1" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="second_step">
      ....
      ....
      ....
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**The instantiation js code plus logic (myform.js)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var first_step = $("#first_step");
    var second_step = $("#second_step");

    $("#myform").validationEngine('attach', {
        promptPosition : "centerRight", 
        scroll: false
    });

    $("#next1").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var valid = $("#myform").validationEngine('validate');          

        if (valid == true) {
            second_step.show(); 
        } else {
            $("#ithemiscustomerform").validationEngine();
        }
    });

});
```

**The rules “validationEngine-el.js”**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.validationEngineLanguage = function(){
    };
    $.validationEngineLanguage = {
        newLang: function(){
            $.validationEngineLanguage.allRules = {
                "required": { // Add your regex rules here, you can take telephone as an example
                    "regex": "none",
                    "alertText": "* Υποχρεωτικό πεδίο",
                    "alertTextCheckboxMultiple": "* Παρακαλώ επιλέξτε",
                    "alertTextCheckboxe": "* Υποχρεωτικό πεδίο",
                    "alertTextDateRange": "* Και τα δύο πεδία ημ/νίας είναι υποχρεωτικά"
                },


                // --- CUSTOM RULES -- Those are specific to the demos, they can be removed or changed to your likings
                "email": {
                    "url": "http://localhost/userformServer/validator.cfc?method=valEmail",
                    // you may want to pass extra data on the ajax call
                    //"extraData": "name=eric",
                    "alertText": "* Μη έγκυρο email",
                    "alertTextLoad": "* Παρακαλώ περιμένετε...",
                    "alertTextOk": "* Το eimail είναι διαθέσιμο"
                },

                "integer": {
                    "regex": /^[\-\+]?\d+$/,
                    "alertText": "* Μη έγκυρος ακέραιος"
                }
            };

        }
    };
    $.validationEngineLanguage.newLang();

})(jQuery);
```

**The problem**

Remote validation works great for the “email” field “on blur” –while user completing the form. But when I click the “next1” button to move on the next fieldset (“second_step”) even if the email field is valid (remotely valid) the form doesn’t move to the next fieldset (see “myform.js” onclick). Specifically when I call “$("#myform").validationEngine('validate');” inside the click event it returns false. I think this occurs due the asynchronous nature of validation. Is there any workaround for this?